# Cannot Find Relative Import Within Module Python

Tags: python, import, pypi

I coudn't find a solution to this problem online. I'm pretty sure this doesn't have anything to do with relative imports but how pypi packages up a directory.

I have my directory structure like this:

```
autocord
├── types
│   ├── Message.py
│   ├── Attachment.py
│   ├── Deleted.py
│   ├── DmChannel.py
│   ├── Embed.py
│   ├── Me.py
│   └── Member.py
├── __init__.py
├── client.py
├── errors.py
└── op.py
```

When I have the autocord directory inside my workspace and import it using `import autocord` everything works fine. However, once I published it to pypi, I get this error when I install it on another workspace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import autocord
  File "/home/runner/autocord-test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autocord/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/home/runner/autocord-test/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autocord/client.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .types.Me import Me
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autocord.types'
```

Here are the imports in client.py:

```py
from .types.Me import Me
from .types.Member import Member
from .types.Message import Message
from .types.Deleted import Deleted
from .types.DmChannel import DmChannel
```

Here is setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    readme = f.read()

setup(
    name="autocord",
    version="1.4.8",
    author="walker",
    description="Discord API wrapper centered around automation",
    long_description=readme,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=['autocord'],
    url="https://github.com/wa1ker38552/autocord",
    install_requires=["requests", "websocket_client"],
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    py_modules=["autocord"]
)
```

You can use `pip install autocord` to test it out for yourself.

Comment: Try putting a blank `__init__.py` file inside the `types` folder.

Comment: Tried that, and then removed it aswell

Comment: Should I try importing inside the `__init__.py`?

Comment: Is the folder structure different when you install from pypi?

Comment: Your `py_modules=["autocord"]` doesn't install anything at all. Please learn the difference between `py_modules` and `packages`: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html